# Counting lowercase in arguments?

Tags: java, arguments, counter

Hello I need help counting lowercase characters only in a command line argument. Right now my code counts all the characters, I cannot figure out how to just have it count lowercase only.

```
public class Characters {
  public static void main(String[] args) {        
    int count = 0;
    for (String string : args) {
      count += string.length(); 
    }
    System.out.println(count);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you add a tag with the language (Java?) it will help people find your question. Also if you correctly indent the code it will make it easier for people to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `java.lang.Character.isLowerCase`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); ++i) {
    if (Character.isLowerCase(string.charAt(i))) {
        ++count;
    }
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLowerCase(char)